# Calculate number of page entries

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual, paging

I have made some research about how this is being calculated and was unable to get a satisfiable answer.

I was trying to solve this " A computer with 512 kb of physical address and 32 kb pages.
1. How many entries are needed in the page table if traditional paging is used?
2. How many entries would have been needed if the pages were 16 kb?

I understand that the amount of amount of entries in the Table equals that of Pages in virtual address space.
but I could not figure out if I am wrong or not.

Answers would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no correct answer to that question with the information provided.

Comment: What is traditional paging ?